# Controlling ELF file size using linker script

Tags: image, linker, arm, elf, linaro

I am generating an ELF file for ARM platform using linaro tool chain.
The file is an executable that is supposed to run bare-metal.

I use a linker script to select the locations of sections in the memory because I want to put specific sections in specific locations.

The problem is that when I move some section forward in the memory I see that the image size increases, although no additional data has been added.

When I run `readelf -a elf_file` I see that both the virtual address (see `Address` field below) and the offset in image (See `Offset` field below) are both increased.

**Example:**

The following lines in the linker script

`. = 0x2000000;
.__translations_block_0 : { TM_TranslationTables.o(__translations_block_0) }`

Result in the following offsets in the elf file (output from readelf)

`[Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset         Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [10] .tdata            PROGBITS         0000000000279000  00279080       000000000000000c  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     16
  [11] .tbss             NOBITS           0000000000279080  0027908c       0000000000011bcc  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     16
  [12] .__translations_b PROGBITS         0000000002000000  02000080       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [13] .__translations_b PROGBITS         0000000002001000  02001080       0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8`

My question is:

Is there a way to increase the address of some section without blowing the image size? I just want the section to be loaded into memory address 0x2000000, I don't want the image size to be 0x2000000.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, what you're doing is moving the location counter in the `.tbss` section, and only then declaring the new section.  Can you try `.__translations_block_0 0x2000000 : ...` ?

Comment: That didn't help.. Still getting the same image

Comment: Did you remove the `. = 0x2000000` line?

Comment: Yes.. is it supposed to work according to the ARM ELF standard?

Comment: I thought it'd work from a quick skimming of https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-Description.html#Output-Section-Description